# 2008 Saturn Vue wont start after putting in new ECM

Tags: saturn, security, crankshaft, electronic-control-module

I put in a new ECM and tried to relearn the key but my security light does not come on and stay on. I did a reading and it gave code p0315. Can someone please help me to figure it out?

Comment: Was the new ecm programmed to the car?

Comment: are you sure that was the right ECM? where do you buy this ECM? new or recondition?

Answer (score 1):

**The missing security light means the ecu you have installed is not good, not compatible or just has the wrong calibrations installed on it.**

There are two ways to do this. The right way with GM tools or J2534 or the backyard mechanic way.

**The right way:**
I usually use tech2 or a cardaq with GM SPS from ACDELCOTDS
Your goal is to Replace+Program the PCM so that the latest programming calibrations are installed and your cars VIN number will be written to the unit. After the pcm updates then you need to go into the PK3+ system (immobilizer) usually listed as VTD.

**Backyard mechanic way (with no scan tools):**
Buy a used pcm with all same part # as original, helps if you buy one where they write your vin for you or else you will have an incorrect VIN and ABS mismatch messages but you can still get the car to run normally otherwise. The main thing you will need to do is program the key. YOU CAN do this with out any tools (if you have a US model only).
Hook up a battery maintainer and do the following:

- Turn the original key to the "ON" position and leave it there for over 10 minutes. (do not crank). The security light will go out.
- Turn Key off & then back to the "ON" position for another 10+ minutes. The light will go out again.
- Turn Key off & then back on for one final 10+ minute wait. The light will go out again. After this you turn the key off and all is done.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to perform the relearn is with a professional level scan tool. Most shops will charge a half hour labor to perform this for you.

The anti theft will need to be done by the dealer as shown below

Theft Deterrent Control Module Programming and Setup

1. Connect a scan tool to the vehicle in the Pass-thru arrangement.
2. Turn ON the ignition, with the engine OFF.
3. Ensure that all power consuming devices are turned OFF on the vehicle.
4. On the Techline Terminal, select Service Programming System and follow the Techline Terminal on-screen instructions, using the Legacy Pass-Thru method. Ensure the correct programming selection is chosen based on component being replaced or programmed. For this procedure, go to the TDM - Theft Deterrent Module menu and select the proper on-screen options.
5. After the programming has completed, turn the ignition OFF for 30 seconds.
6. Turn ON the ignition with the engine OFF.
7. On the Techline Terminal, select Service Programming System and follow the Techline Terminal on-screen instructions, using the Legacy Pass-Thru method. Ensure the correct programming selection is chosen based on component being replaced or programmed. For this procedure, go to the V.T.D. Vehicle Theft Deterrent Learn menu and choose the Vehicle Theft Deterrent Learn, ECM, or PK3 Replaced selection.
8. At this point the scan tool must remain connected for the duration of the 10-minute relearn procedure.

Important:

- The scan tool will initially display 12 Minutes. The first 2 minutes allow the scan tool to initialize the appropriate control module. The remaining 10 minutes is the relearn timer.
- On some vehicles the security indicator may be illuminated for the duration of the 10-minute relearn procedure.

Observe the scan tool, after approximately 10 minutes the scan tool will display "Programming Successful, Turn OFF Ignition". The vehicle is now ready to relearn the key information and/or the passwords on the next ignition switch transition from OFF to CRANK.

9. Turn OFF the ignition and wait 2 minutes.
10. With a master vehicle key, turn the ignition to the RUN position for 15 seconds, then start the vehicle. The TDM and ECM have now relearned the pre-release password ***** the challenge/response data.
11. With a scan tool, clear any DTCs.

Comment: You can manually program pass-key, pk3, pk3+, etc...GM's on US models.